# Verifying Multipath I/O on Hyper-V (non-Core, Enterprise host with Hyper-V role)

Tags: hyper-v, multipath

Finding the dialog/menus a bit confusing in comparison to vCenter/VMware.  I believe I have Multipath I/O configured (added Multipath I/O role, rebooted, added additional connection under Connections and see two active connections with Round Robin configured).

Besides yanking cables on switches, where else can I look?  Thought I saw a screenshot of a shell command that showed rather succinctly that the multipathing was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to look at the connection statistics of our SAN device.  Our Dell MD3000i had a whole host of Tx and Rx stats we could use to diagnose and monitor the multipath connectivity.

Comment: Right, yeah, never thought of looking on the SAN side, but of course (same with the switch statistics): that would also tell if the load balancing is working properly.  VMWare shows pretty good statistics as well in the Performance tab; don't have System Center setup so lacking that kind of clarity on the hypervisor side at the moment.

Comment: @gravyface Yea, we just had the Hyper-V manager and it does not show any type of IO in the manager.  You could however setup individual perfmons to look at specific ethernet port activity and view it that way as well.  But the SAN for us was always easier to pull up, plus it knew exactly what client was connected and from what IP.